# How to add a custom popup action to the default Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Ah I've searched all around but mostly I found threads about how to add custom actions for a custom menu or a custom editor, not for the original editor of Eclipse.

And since the **org.eclipse.ui.popMenus** is deprecated, I consider using **org.eclipse.ui.menus**.

So how to add a custom popup action to the default Eclipse editor
Like here I want to tweak the context menu in Java editor

Comment: Which 'original' editor? There are many editors even in the most basic Eclipse install.

Comment: sorry for that lack of details, the editor I'm refering to here is the one in which we write our codes...

Comment: Code in what programming language?

Comment: oh here it's java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context menu for the Java editor seems to have the id of `#CompilationUnitEditorContext`. You can contribute to the context menu using something like:

```xml
<extension 
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         allPopups="false"
         locationURI="popup:#CompilationUnitEditorContext?before=additions">
      <command
            commandId="your.command.id"
            style="push">
      </command>
   </menuContribution>
```

where `your.command.id` is the id of a `command` that you define.

Comment: thanks for the example. btw another question here I have is how should I define a command and assocaite it with some functions I want, for instance I can set commandId to "org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace" to enable find and replace funciton in context menu.

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` and `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension points [Eclipse Commands](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)